# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required to install twisted where Visual studio 2017 is already installed

Tags: visual-studio-code, kivy, twisted, python-3.7

When i compiled the code in VS-Code gives error -> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

[image]Installing twisted in (windows 10)
1:     **pip install python-twisted** gives an error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-twisted (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-twisted

2: **pip/pip3 install twisted**

Failed building wheel for twisted
  Running setup.py clean for twisted
  Failed to build twisted
**Note:**  There are two python versions installed in my PC But python command gives the actual version **3.7.2 an i am using it**. Where the other one is 3.6.6 just residing in my disk

I have already installed visual studio along with python but **working on visual studio code**. It was good util this program!

I have tried 2 methods(mentioned u there) to install twisted and many other answers on stack overflow to resolve the issue.

I am following the kivy documentation and expecting it to work well

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to stackoverflow.  The code in the question doesn't seem relevant.  The error occurs before any of your application code gets to run.  I suggest removing it.  I also suggest specifying exactly the version of Python you're using.  It's not clear now whether you're using Python 3.6.6 or Python 3.7.2.  I also suggest mentioning exactly what things you've tried to fix this already instead of just saying "many other answers".  There are many answers on SO.  We don't know which ones you've tried.

Comment: OK, see it done!

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you tried.  "pip install python-twisted" and "pip install twisted", I guess?  "python-twisted" is not the name of the package so there's no chance that will ever work.  "pip install twisted" probably should work.  Maybe you need to "pip install wheel" first but just guessing since I still don't really know much about your environment.

Comment: Here's the tutorial **python-twisted** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxfyV3cyjOI

Comment: It's done **VC++ Toolset for desktop** was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install VC++14.0 compiler. You could download installer for Visual Studio 2017 or 2019, and ask for VC++2015 v14.0 to be installed.

[image]

This is how it looks in my VS 2017 installation. You might download just command line compiler as well, but I never tried it. Link to download https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: @Kaleem Good luck!